# Why does this equation work?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, logarithms

let $ P(x) := \sum_{p \leq x} Log [p]$, then we have

- $P(2^{k+1}) = \sum_{i=0}^k ( P(2^{i+1}) - P(2^i)) < 2 \cdot Log[2] \cdot (1 + 2 + 4 +... + 2^k) \leq 4 \cdot Log[2] \cdot 2^k$.

Why does this equation work?

The first step is clear for me, since we have a telescope sum.
However, how can I conclude to the first $<$ and the $\leq$ ?

Comment: What is $T(.)?$

Comment: The last $\le$ is easy because $\sum_{i=0}^k2^i=2^{k+1}-1=2\cdot 2^k - 1 \le 2 \cdot 2^k.$

Comment: Hi, sorry that was a mistake. $T$ should be $P$ as defined $P(x) := ..$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now, the solution is pretty simple, since

- $P(2n) - P(n) < 2\cdot Log[2] \cdot n$,

which can be shown fast, we can conclude the above inequality by setting

- $2n = 2^{i+1}$ and $n = 2^{i+1} / 2 = 2^i$ and then summing up.

Thanks for your help.